# Have a bent frying pan

Tags: equipment

I have a frying pan that was dropped and is now bent making it where the lid doesn't sit correctly on it.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you have a frying pan flimsy enough to be warped by dropping to the point where the lid does not fit, this is not a quality pan that you want to be cooking with.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I dunno, if the lid fits pretty well, all it'd take is a little deformation on the edge, might happen pretty easily on a hard floor.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Perfectly good domestic fry pans are made or lightweight metals like aluminium. For ease of handling, cleaning, and to save energy. Why heat up masses of cast iron or copper to fry an egg.

Comment: Before discarding it, use it on your bbq to pan fry something. Now you have a dedicated outdoor bbq pan!

Answer (score 3):

Holding a bit of 2X4 (wood) up to the bent edge and banging on the wood with a hammer works for aluminum pans. If steel, but not too thick, the technique should work as well. You have to start slow, with light hits, to get a feel for how much deformation you get for force applied. Don't use a hammer directly on the pan surface, it'll likely leave damaged areas.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that might be worth trying is to just bang it back into shape. An auto body repair shop could probably do it in seconds. It would be a novelty for them, it wouldn't surprise me if they would do it for free. The pan might never quite be right though.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this video, cut a piece of wood into two pieces that have the same curve as a part of the pan that is NOT damaged.  Then clamp the wood on the damaged area and tighten until the bent portion conforms to the curve of the wood

https://youtu.be/Nrw12oIBUIs?